# Inserting data into a related database. C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I've got two tables that i'm trying to insert data into with my C# application. They related with the ID.

I've read afew questions on how to do this but none of them have worked, I've now decided to do them as separate sql queries.

```
 private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //table 1
            String acctCode = tbAcctCode.Text;
            String address1 = tbAdd1.Text;
            String address2 = tbAdd2.Text;
            String address3 = tbAdd3.Text;
            String balance = tbBalance.Text;
            String yearSales = tbSales.Text;
            String yearCost = tbCost.Text;
            //table 2
            String date = tbDate.Text;
            String transaction = tbTrans.Text;
            String docNum = tbDocNum.Text;
            String grossVal = tbGross.Text;
            String vatVal = tbVat.Text;

            //SQL statement set to Add a new value
            sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO "+ table1 + "(Account_Code,Address1,Address2,Address3,Balance,Sales_Year_To_Date,Cost_Year_To_Date) " +
                                 "VALUES " +
                                 "('{0}'," + "{1}," + "{2}," + "'{3}'," + "'{4}'," + "{5}," + "'{6}');", acctCode, address1, address2, address3, balance, yearSales, yearCost);

            sql2 = String.Format("INSERT INTO " + table2 + "(Date,Transaction_Type,Document_No,Gross_Transaction_Value,Vat_Value) " +
                                 "VALUES " +
                                 "('{0}'," + "'{1}'," + "'{2}'," + "'{3}'," + "'{4}');", date, transaction, docNum, grossVal, vatVal);

            try
            {
                dbConn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
                dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

                dbConn.Open();
                dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql2, dbConn);
                dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            catch (SqlException E)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            finally
            {
                dbConn.Close();
            }

        }
    }
```

The data is inserted into the first table fine but the problem comes in at the OleDbCommand of the sql2. "It throws a System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'"

I've got a feeling something in my sql syntax is wrong but I can't spot it.

Comment: _"I've got a feeling something in my sql syntax is wrong but I can't spot it."_ Yes, you dont use sql parameters ;-)

Comment: what is the value of `sql2` before execution?

Comment: this is sql2 before its executed. "INSERT INTO Debtors_Transaction_File(Date,Transaction_Type,Document_No,Gross_Transaction_Value,Vat_Value) VALUES ('2017/12/06','EFT','6','150','50');"

Comment: As @TimSchmelter noted, you should use parameterized queries to mitigate the possibility of SQL injection attacks and escape text where appropriate. It will also make your queries a little easier to read in code. See [msdn example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbparameter.aspx). There is also no need for you to be concatenating your String Format params together  (which reduces readability).

Comment: date is a reserved word?  but do use parameters, and also the semicolon at the end is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try This Would Be Prefect

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //SQL statement set to Add a new value
        sql = String.Format("INSERT INTO " + table1 + "(Account_Code,Address1,Address2,Address3,Balance,Sales_Year_To_Date,Cost_Year_To_Date) " +
                             "VALUES " + (@acctCode, @address1, @address2, @address3, @balance, @yearSales, @yearCost));

        sql2 = String.Format("INSERT INTO " + table2 + "([Date],Transaction_Type,Document_No,Gross_Transaction_Value,Vat_Value)" +
                             "VALUES " + (@date, @transaction, @docNum, @grossVal, @vatVal));


        try
        {
            dbConn = new OleDbConnection(conString);
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, dbConn);

            //table 1
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acctCode", tbAcctCode.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address1", tbAdd1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address2", tbAdd2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address3", tbAdd3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@balance", tbBalance.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearSales", tbSales.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yearCost", tbCost.Text);

            dbConn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql2, dbConn);

            //table 2
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", tbDate.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@transaction", tbTrans.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@docNum", tbDocNum.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@grossVal", tbGross.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@vatVal", tbVat.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException E)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(E.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        finally
        {
            dbConn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of "dbCmd = new OleDbCommand(sql2, dbConn)" you could far better use" dbCmd.CommandText = sql2;"

Comment: and did you check if having the field name called "Date" in the second table is the issue?

Comment: This is what im getting on the very first parameter-"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

cmd was null"

Comment: Because Parameters Were Declared before Command Try Edited Answer This Would Be Perfect..

Comment: With the edit i posted it works, but now i'm back to my original error where I get the System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement.'" from my original question.

Comment: Just tried creating a dummy database. It's the Date Field. You should enclose in square brackets because Date is a reserved keyword. use [date]